# Simak story about a man who finds a robot braincase buried underground

Tags: story-identification, clifford-d-simak

He takes the braincase home, hooks it up to a computer and finds that it is still active. And that it has been writing stories all the time it was buried. He takes the stories as his own and becomes a best-selling author.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a short story?  Did you read it in a magazine or an anthology?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is almost definitely "[Earth for Inspiration](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71349)" (1941) by Clifford D. Simak.

At the beginning of the story a robot, Philbert, is wandering alone on a desolate, mostly abandoned late-stage Earth, victim of a crash that killed his pilot.  He moves as long as he can, trying to find a spaceport, his limbs giving out and then ultimately his sensors, leaving him stranded, thinking:

> The right leg was dragging now and fear hammered at him. "I'm getting batty," he moaned. "I'm beginning to imagine things, and only humans do that. Only humans—" His voice box croaked and rasped and slipped a cog. The leg gave out and he crawled. Then his arms gave out and he lay still. The sand hissed against his metal body.
>
> "Someone will find me," Philbert rattled hoarsely.
>
> But no one found him. Philbert's body became a rusted hulk. His hearing went first and after that his eyes failed one by one. His body became flakes of dull red metal. But inside its almost indestructible case, lubricated by sealed-in-oil, Philbert's brain still clicked.

He composes fantasies as he lies there:

> Philbert was, by nature, thorough.  He never did a thing by halves. He built up impossible situations, devised great travels and adventures, accepted shaky premises and theories, dallied with metaphysical speculation. He wandered to improbable dimensions, conversed with strange beings that lived on unknown worlds, battled with
> vicious entities that spawned outside the pale of time and space, rescued civilizations tottering on the brink of horrible destruction.
>
> The years galloped on and on, but Philbert didn't notice. He was having him a time.

Jerome Duncan is a once-successful author who has not been selling stories anymore.  His robot Jenkins convinces him to travel to find some inspiration:

> "Why don't you visit some of these places you are writing about?" the robot suggested. "Why don't you take a vacation and see if you can't gather some local color and some inspiration?" Duncan scratched his head.
>
> "Maybe you got something there, Jenkins," he admitted. He glanced at the returned manuscript, thumbed through its pages.
>
> "This one should have sold. It's an Old Earth story and they're always
> popular."
>
> He shoved the manuscript away from him and stood up.
>
> "Jenkins, call up Galactic Transportation and find out the schedule to Old
> Earth."

On Old Earth, Duncan finds the last tribe of humans, whose leader is "the Thunderer" and they discover a robot's braincase.

> "But, Chief," protested Duncan, "this isn't just a piece of junk. This is a robot's brain case."
>
> "Yeah?" piped the Thunderer.
>
> "Sure," declared Duncan. "Look at the serial number, right down here." He bent his head closer to the number and whistled in surprise. "Look, Chief. This case is about three million years old! Only ten digits. This year's models have sixteen."

Duncan hooks up Philbert's brain in Jenkin's body and they discover that Philbert tells *amazing* stories.  Duncan takes Philbert home, and starts selling Philbert's stories as his own.

If you'd like to read the whole story, it's [here in the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ThrillingWonderStoriesV20N01194104/page/n97/mode/2up).

Comment: Thanks, David W. I couldn't find a trace of this story anywhere. I was beginning to think I had the wrong author or that I had imagined the whole thing.